# Returning a list using LINQ

Tags: linq, list

I want to return a list of objects stored in a database using LINQ queries.

I tried the following

```
public BO.Hotel getHotels()
{
    TripBagEntities db = new TripBagEntities();

    var hotels = (from m in db.HotelEntities
                  where m.id < 10
                  select m).ToList().First();

    return Mapper.ToHotelObject(hotels);
}
```

This returns only the first item in the list. How can I return the entire list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take out the call to `First()`. (you should understand what you code is doing before you start asking questions about it)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as per the comment, you should understand exactly what each line of your existing code does first. (You should also try to follow .NET naming conventions.) If you're guessing around which bit of your code does what, it would be a good idea to read a good tutorial geared towards the LINQ provider you're using (Entity Framework?).

We don't really know what `Mapper.ToHotelObject` does, or whether there's already a method for converting a whole sequence. This should work though:

```
public List<BO.Hotel> GetHotels()
{
    // Note: you may want a using statement here...
    TripBagEntities db = new TripBagEntities();
    var hotels = db.HotelEntities
                   .Where(m => m.id < 10)
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(Mapper.ToHotelObject)
                   .ToList();
}
```

Or if the method group conversion doesn't work:

```
public List<BO.Hotel> GetHotels()
{
    // Note: you may want a using statement here...
    TripBagEntities db = new TripBagEntities();
    var hotels = db.HotelEntities
                   .Where(m => m.id < 10)
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(m => Mapper.ToHotelObject(m))
                   .ToList();
}
```

Note that I've used "dot notation" for the whole query, as it makes life simpler when you're using things like `AsEnumerable` and `ToList`, and your query expression wasn't complicated anyway.

The `AsEnumerable` call "shifts" the query into LINQ to Objects, so that the query-to-SQL translation part doesn't need to try to convert `Mapper.ToHotelObject` into SQL, which I assume would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function return `List<BO.Hotel>` instead of a Hotel, and adjust your query and  Mapper function accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I will have to remove .First() too right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<BO.Hotel> getHotels()
    {
        TripBagEntities db = new TripBagEntities();
        return (from m in db.HotelEntities
                     where m.id < 10
                      select Mapper.ToHotelObject(m)).ToList();
    }
```